# Cartesian Tensor Algebra - Symmetric and Antisymmetric Tensors

Tags: tensors

I need to show that for an antisymmetric cartesian tensor $\Omega_{ij}$, 
$$ \Omega_{il} x_l x_j - \Omega_{jk} x_k x_i = 2 K_{ik} \Omega_{kj}$$
where $K_{ij} = x_i x_j$ and $x_i$ are position coordinates.

I realise $\Omega$ is antisymmetric and $K$ is symmetric, but I cant use these properties to get to the result, unless I assume $T_{ij} = \Omega_{il} x_l x_j$ is antisymmetric in $ij$. I know this is probably basic but I'm stuck. Any hints would be much appreciated :).

Comment: Are you using he summation convention on repeated indices?  So that, for example, $\Omega_{il}x_lx_j = \sum_l\Omega_{il}x_lx_j$?

Comment: Yes, I should have included that sorry